# Django: is there a difference in performance between accessing the database from a view or from the template (with Template Language)?

Tags: django, database, django-templates

I have been wondering for a while now. Is there a difference if for example i get a list of objects in the view and pass it to the template as context variable or if i do some gymnastics in the template and reach the information directly?

For example: view + template query

```
#view
context = {
    'orders' : Order.objects.filter(user=user),
}

#template
{% for order in orders %}
    {{ order }}
{% endfor %}
```

Vs.

```
{% for order in user.orders.all %}
    {{ order }}
{% endfor %}
```

Would the pure template query be slower because it has to perform more operations? If there is a difference how many orders would the query have to retrieve in order to have a noticeable difference between the two solutions?

Comment: There would only be a minor difference between the two (the time taken by the template engine to parse the statement `user.orders.all` and make the actual call to the method). Otherwise both queries are equivalent (at least in the example you give, the difference would not even be noticeable).

Comment: Although in the template we cannot use `select_related` or `prefetch_related` (at least properly) so if we want to get related objects of the objects we loop over this would create a bottleneck and decrease speed.